# Rstudio with administration rights can't find R

Tags: rstudio

I want to knit a pdf document in Markdown. To do it I need tinytex which is blocked by group policy.  I have previously been able to install tinytex and knit pdf's by opening RStudio as an administrator. Suddenly I can't do that anymore because RStudio can't find R (error message: R does not appear to be installed. Please install R before using RStudio). Does anybody have any tips on how to solve this problem?

I'm using:
Windows 10 Enterprise
Rstudio 2023.09.0
R 4.3.1

I have reinstalled both Rstudio and R (newest versions). Both programs have been innstalled to the same location (C:Program Files). Everything works fine when I open RStudio like normal (not as administrator)

Comment: If you can get administrator privileges, why do use them to work around the group policy? Wouldn't it be more straightforward to change the group policy using your admin rights to allow tinytex?

Comment: Won't I have to open Rstudio to allow tinytex? Or do I do that elsewhere